# specify npm dependency from google cloud storage

Tags: npm

How can I specify a dependency in my package.json which is available in google cloud storage

Due to some reason - we cannot host it in github, neither publish on npm

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer myself.

You can compress (tar) your package and upload it on a publicly accessible google storage link and then you can specify the dependency as:

```
"package-name": "https://storage.googleapis.com/path/to/package/package-name.tar",
```